# Azure Database for MySQL and Azure VM replication connection error

Tags: mysql, azure, replication, azure-virtual-machine, azure-database-mysql

I have provisioned a Azure Database for MySQL instance and
for the purposes of debugging I have added to the rule under the connection security section as below:

Name: allowAll
Start IP: 0.0.0.0
End IP: 247.255.255.255

It does not allow me to specify a port, I have assumed the above rule allows all traffic to flow freely to the Azure Database for MySQL.

I also have an Azure VM which I have created that runs MySQL, I wish to setup replication between the VM and Azure Database for MySQL instance.

Master(VM) ---> Slave (Azure Database for MySQL)

Again for the purposes of testing I have created the following network security group rules for the purposes of debugging only

Inbound security rules:
Priority: 1000
Name: test
Port: Any
Protocol: Any
Source: Any
Destination: Any
Action: Allow

Outbound security rules:
Priority: 1000
Name: test
Port: Any
Protocol: Any
Source: Any
Destination: Any
Action: Allow

To my knowledge the above should eliminate any possibility of the connection being blocked at network level.

When I attempt to start MySQL replication I get the following error

"Last_IO_Errno: 2003
"Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'X@X.X.X.X:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1"

**Real details switched with X's for security**

I have created users on both the MySQL instance with wildcard hostname access and have verified I can connect from my home connection.

On the Azure VM I can run tcpdump and I am able to see traffic flowing to and from the Azure VM to Azure Database like below

"X.X.X.X.3306 > X.X.X.X.28288: Flags [S.], cksum 0x2564 (incorrect -> 0xd59b), seq 4079747372, ack 1378238510, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:15:25.762288 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)"

Is anyone able to provide any help here ?

Comment: Have you enabled "allow access to Azure services" for your Azure DB for MySQL server? Additionally, is SSL enabled on the MySQL server?

Comment: Did you solve this ? Running into the same issue here